# Facebook App on Azure using ASP.NET MVC Facebook Template (API Error Code: 191)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, templates, azure

I try deploying my first Facebook App on Azure using ASP.NET MVC Facebook Template as an [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/31/deploying-your-first-facebook-app-on-azure-using-asp-net-mvc-facebook-template.aspx). I do not do anything extra, just what in the example.

But every time I get an error:

> API Error Code: 191.
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application

I checked all the Names and AppId and AppSecret. Everything is correct. I do not understand what went wrong.

Maybe it's because "*This template is still in a preview state. The APIs could change significantly before the final release*"?

Or is there a problem with an example?

Comment: Did you correctly defined your Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL in your **facebook** app - to correspond to your Azure Websites website URL alias? It is most common reason for that error.

Comment: A very interesting question. I tried reproduce this error by changing Canvs URL and Secure Canvas URL. But I could not. If I enter a non-existent URL, or for example http://facebook.stackoverflow.com, the error was other. I also tried to spoil the AppId and AppSecret in my Azure app, but the error was also different.

Comment: My Canvas URL: http://<myname>.azurewebsites.net/ 
My Secure Canvas URL: https://<myname>.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for this error is when your app on Facebook has a namespace but you didn't set the "Facebook:AppNamespace" in the configuration. See the updated tutorial for more information: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-mvc/facebook-application-template-tutorial.